# Jmeter: Why are my JSON assertions failing because of a question mark?

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, assertion

I am testing a menu/restaurant chat bot, and need to validate that it received the exact input I typed. I query a debugger to get the input back.

My input string is `What is cocktail?`. This is the response:

```
    "userInputs": {
    "originalInput": {
      "sentence": "What is cocktail?",
      "timestamp": 2088408809
      }
     },
```

So it is definitely getting the correct input. The error seems to be in my JSON assertion. Here it is, getting the data from a CSV file (where `input` = What  is cocktail?).

[image]

My assertion then fails with the message `Input : Value expected to match regexp '(?i)What is cocktail?', but it did not match: 'What is cocktail?'`

They look the same to me, except for the regex. If I remove the question mark, the test passes. Am I missing something obvious with regular expressions, that I can't have a question mark in my string?

Comment: Ok, I found that you need to escape the question mark. But how do I do that when it is included in the input string? Is the only way to add "\?" to every single question mark in my data set?

Answer (score 0):

Question mark is part of the characters that [must be escaped](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html) in regular expression if you don't want to use their special meaning

> ? the question mark is the match-zero-or-one quantifier.

You can replace value using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

```
vars.put("inputEscaped", vars.get("input").replace("?","\\?"));
```

It will create a new variable `${inputEscaped}` you can use (also you can override `input`)